# MySQL with Aptana Studio3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, aptana

I have Aptana Studio 3.0.2.201106082310 installed with windows vista. Though i have both mysql and sqlite installed but i am not able to make mysql a default database.

I tried to google but i could not find a way to make mysql the default db. It will be great if someone can suggest me how to get it done..